# Can we use an "if" before with-select -VHDL

Tags: select, if-statement, vhdl, xilinx

I have a code like the following,

```
with current_display select
char_output <= hours1 & '1' when "0111",
            hours2 & '1' when "1011",
        mins1 & '1' when "1101",
        mins2 & '1' when  "1110",
        "00000" when others;
```

but I would like to add two or more options to selecting the display of 7-segment. Adding only one option I make this one,

```
with set_alarm_switch & current_display select
        char_output <= hours1 & '1' when "00111",
                hours2 & '1' when "01011",
                mins1 & '1' when    "01101",
                mins2 & '1' when "01110",
                alarm_hours1 & '1' when "10111",
                alarm_hours2 & '1' when "11011",
                alarm_mins1 & '1' when  "11101",
                alarm_mins2 & '1' when  "11110",
                "00000" when others;
```

I wonder if I make this same coding with some "if" statements because if i were to add these guys another property, then I would have a complicated code.

Comment: Are you combining all of your 7 segment displays into one char_output signal?  I would think that you would have 4 signals, one for each 7 segment display.  It would simplify your code if you did that.

Comment: I have another vhdl module for 7 segment display, which assigns these numbers after "when" to a display in hexadecimal. And I think yes it is combining all of my 7 segment displays into one char_output signal. The thing here is, at first I had the first code that I wrote down there but after I came up with another switch assignment which needed to show some other display just in the second codes last four lines. Can you give me an idea? Or should I just add another property and do the same thing just like I did in the second code??? Thx

Comment: If you want to mix "if" with "case" then you need to put it in a process.  I note with VHDL-2008, the selected assignment (as you have above) is allowed in processes, however, prior to that it is not.  As a result, you may have to transform it to an equivalent case statement if you put it in a process.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think all the current answers miss the question: "[...] make this same coding with some "if" statements [...]."

Your current VHDL describes your desired circuit using a parallel assignment statement (with-select). You can easily convert this into multiple sequential statements inside a parallel process:

```
assign_output_p : process (
    -- VHDL-2008: use "all" instead of each signal name
    set_alarm_switch,
    current_display,
    hours1,
    hours2,
    mins1,
    mins2,
    alarm_hours1,
    alarm_hours2,
    alarm_mins1,
    alarm_mins2
    )
begin

    -- default assignment
    char_output <= (others => '0');

    if (set_alarm_switch = '1') then
        -- set alarm case

        case (current_display) is
        when "0111" => 
            char_output <= alarm_hours1 & '1';
        when "1011" => 
            char_output <= alarm_hours2 & '1';
        when "1101" => 
            char_output <= alarm_mins1 & '1';
        when "1110" => 
            char_output <= alarm_mins2 & '1';
        when others => 
            -- case for other current_display values
            -- including XUZ etc.
            null;
        end case;

    else
        -- default case

        case (current_display) is
        when "0111" => 
            char_output <= hours1 & '1';
        when "1011" => 
            char_output <= hours2 & '1';
        when "1101" => 
            char_output <= mins1 & '1';
        when "1110" => 
            char_output <= mins2 & '1';
        when others => 
            -- case for other current_display values
            -- including XUZ etc.
            null;
        end case;
    end if;

end process assign_output_p;
```

Also, I think you should evaluate if this big multiplexer makes sense in your application. Seven-segment displays are not that timing critical, so I advise to include a register stage at some point.
Many companies choose to have a policy about this:

1. Register inputs, leave outputs combinational => assumption that the next module will register them.
2. Combinational inputs, register outputs => assumption that the previous module has registered outputs.

Answer (score 1):

Personally I would treat each 7 segment display as its own signal.  You might have good reasons not to do this, but it makes the most sense to me.  So your code might look like this:

```
seg3 <= hours_tens_time when current_display = '1' else hours_tens_alarm;
seg2 <= hours_ones_time when current_display = '1' else hours_ones_alarm;
seg1 <= mins_tens_time  when current_display = '1' else mins_tens_alarm;
seg0 <= mins_ones_time  when current_display = '1' else mins_ones_alarm;
```

This way, you can add more signals as you want to on seg3, 2, 1, 0, if you want to add a stopwatch or whatever you can do that, just expand this conditional assignment above.  Give your signals more meaningful names too.  `hours1` `hours2` doesn't mean anything.

Comment: By the way, is it clear that this part is the last lines of my main vhdl modules coding? I hope the part that I showed up there made you understand the rest of the code and what it is for clearly. Thanks for this help I will try to convert my 7-segment display lines with this idea.

Comment: @Russell, it really depends on what board you have.  What you have suggested would be appropriate for one of the Terasic Altera boards that have separate lines for each of the segments.  However the Digilent Xilinx boards only have one character output and you multiplex the outputs.  I suspect that the board Alkadian has is more similar to the Xilinx board.

Comment: Ah good to know.  I still would recommend doing the muxing to the 7 segment as late as possible.  The previous example put too much into one select statement IMO.

Comment: It is a Basys2 Digilent Xilinx board. I think I have a code for what you are talking for too,  
`process(clk) --multiplex
 begin
 if rising_edge(clk) then
 divider <= divider + 1;
 if( divider(14) = '1' ) then
current_display <= current_display(0) & current_display(3 downto 1);
 divider <= (others => '0');
  end if;
 end if;
end process; --end multiplex`